# qt application and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator, shared-ptr

I want to create a qt application ( using qt-creator ), that use my library, that was build in VS2010. A library contains a class, that use std::shred_ptr<>

```
#include <memory>
struct MyStruct;

class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass::MyClass();

    protected:
    std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> mMember;
}
```

Then I include library to the application, using [This tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html).
 And gets next errors:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'shared_ptr' with no type
invalid use of '::'
expected ';' before '<' token
```

Is a way to solve this problem?

**PS**Was corrected code( added include and parameter class of shared_ptr ).
But this things already been in original code.
I think, the problem in the qt-creator compiler. But I don't know exactly, because I'm pretty new in qt programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use C++11 flag for compiler. For example, in your **.pro**-file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this solution some time ago. But it still no panacea. It suppress problem with `shared_ptr`, but do not recognize `nullptr` keyword. So I decide - that best solution is to build application on the same compiler, that  library was build. So i'll try to bind vs2010 and qt, and build application using vs2010. Wish me luck))) .

Comment: Not recognize nullptr keyword? Hm... It's strange. VC2010 supports this keyword (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)...

Comment: VS2010 recognize... QtCreator does not

Answer (score 0):

There's no definition of `MyClass2` int the code you shared.

I believe you were trying to do `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mMember;`

Comment: [Here](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/28347/1954) you can find examples similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Include `<memory>` before defining the class. Also make sure `MyClass2` is declared.